# Case statement COUNT for THEN in (PostgreSQL) 9.3.11

Tags: sql, postgresql

Firstly, this is a coursework question, so I am not looking for a full answer, just a hint :)

I have a "monarch" database that stores name, house(?), accession, coronation(?) that keeps track of monarchs (including prime ministers). The house and coronation applies only to monarchs and returns null if monarch is a prime minister.
It looks as follows:

[image: table]

I am required to write a psql query that returns the scheme(house,seventeenth,eighteenth,nineteenth,twentieth), listing the number of monarchs of each royal house that acceded to the throne in the 17th,18th,19th and 20th centuries and have an issue of what to add as my THEN query.

**EDIT:** 
Thank you for your suggestions! I made some changes to my query now:

```
 SELECT  house,
         TO_CHAR(accession, 'YYYY' ) AS accession_year,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN accession_year BETWEEN 1601 AND 1700 THEN name END) AS seventeenth,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN accession_year BETWEEN 1701 AND 1800 THEN name END) AS eighteenth,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN accession_year BETWEEN 1801 AND 1900 THEN name END) AS nineteenth,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN accession_year BETWEEN 1901 AND 2000 THEN name END) AS twentieth,
  FROM monarch
  WHERE house IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY house
  ;
```

Now psql tells me that accession_year does not exist. I do not want to use full accession date in CASE statements. How can I still use my TO_CHAR in the query?

Comment: Count(1) will be fine . @a_horse_with_no_name how will it be a case expression without then ?

Comment: sorry, that was stupid. I was somehow thinking of `else`. Just use `then 1 end`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I applied the changes but psql tells me that accession_year does not exist. I do not want to use full accession date in CASE statements. How can I still use my TO_CHAR in the query?

Comment: Also need to add `accession` in `Group by`

Comment: Thank you Jaydip! And as far as TO_CHAR is concerned, do I have to use variable to calculate it first, then select it? I don't understand why it says it does not exist?

Comment: Thank you for being up-front about this being coursework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each expression in a single `SELECT` clause is evaluated "as if" it's being computed in parallel with all other expressions in the same clause. As such, you're not allowed to have any dependencies between them since no resulting values are available at the start.

One option is to introduce a subquery:

```
SELECT  house,
         accession_year,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN accession_year BETWEEN 1601 AND 1700 THEN name END) AS seventeenth,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN accession_year BETWEEN 1701 AND 1800 THEN name END) AS eighteenth,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN accession_year BETWEEN 1801 AND 1900 THEN name END) AS nineteenth,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN accession_year BETWEEN 1901 AND 2000 THEN name END) AS twentieth,
  FROM (
     SELECT house,name,TO_CHAR(accession, 'YYYY' ) AS accession_year
     FROM monarch
     WHERE house IS NOT NULL ) AS t
  GROUP BY house
  ;
```

Where now you have two separate `SELECT` clauses and the outer one *is* allowed to depend on values computed by the inner one.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much, that really explains why accession_year did not yet exist!

Answer (score 2):

You can use sub-selects OR CTEs to `SELECT` (or just use) calculated columns, but in some simpler cases (like yours) a [`LATERAL` join](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) is more readable:

```
SELECT   house,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN accession_century = 17 THEN 1 END) AS seventeenth,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN accession_century = 18 THEN 1 END) AS eighteenth,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN accession_century = 19 THEN 1 END) AS nineteenth,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN accession_century = 20 THEN 1 END) AS twentieth
FROM     monarch,
         date_part('century', accession) accession_century
WHERE    house IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY house
```

**Note:** `to_char()` returns a string, which is not really useful for querying, use `date_part()` or `EXTRACT()` instead. Especially in your case: they have the ability to extract the century, which you want to search for.

Comment: This looks so elegant! However, I am gettng "function expression in FROM cannot refer to other relations of same query level
LINE 22:     date_part('century', accession) accession_century"

Comment: @qwerty `LATERAL` joins (and sub-queries) are added to PostgreSQL in 9.3. If you use a [version before that](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/), you will get the error message you mentioned (also, please tag your question with, or mention in the description the exact version you use).

Comment: Oh I see,  my apologies. The version that I run queries against is (PostgreSQL) 9.3.11.

Comment: I'm so sorry to bother, but I keep on getting the error if i use accession in date_part, if i use 'date current', it works fine. Do you have any idea why is it happening?

Comment: @qwerty It should not happen in or after 9.3, but I only have 9.4 to test it right now (it works fine in that). If you can try it out in this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/432df) (for me, it doesn't do anything right now, not even `select * from table`). Please try to make sure that you use the 9.3 version. You can double check that with `SELECT version()`.

Comment: thank you for all the help! I double checked the version (both with psql --version and your suggestion) and it is the 9.3.11. What I mean is that everything works perfectly fine (i.e. I get correct results) if I use your query with either a hardcoded date in date_part - e.g. "date_part('century', date '200-01-01') accession_century" , but it shows an error if I use the name of a column that contains the dates. Error I get is: "function expression in FROM cannot refer to other relations of same query level". Does it mean there is an issue with the column? Sorry to be bothering so much.

Comment: @qwerty this should [work on 9.3 too](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/432df/3). Your error message still indicates that you are using a version pre-9.3 (before `LATERAL` support was added)